# Simple Background Image, Django unable to find image

Tags: html, django

Just wanting to make a simple multiple page website and I cant seem to get the background image to show on local host, Django just keeps saying Image not found. Can anyone help with this?? I want to drop vue in and do some fun stuff, but If I can't even get the images to show its going to be no fun at all.

The HTML File.

```
<body>
    <section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <div id="bg">
        <div class="bg">
          <img
            src="{% static "media/ocean.jpg" %}"
            class="bg1"
            alt=""
          />
```

My View File

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, '/Users/mossboss/Dev/SimpleWS/apps/core/templates/core/base.html')
```

My Settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

Comment: Did you do: `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Thank you jrd1 I just tried it and i'm getting this error You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: @jrd1 I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @jrd1 So I fixed the error and django is still not finding the image.

Comment: Is the image already in the `static` directory?

Comment: I'm uncertain why that didn't work, however I'm seeing something in the code you shared which could explain why. The paths `BASE_DIR / 'static'` and `MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'` are quite surprising to me - another method for path concatenation should be used. Moreover, Python should have raised an error and the code should not run at all, much less indicate that an image was not found. What does your terminal show when you attempt to run the above code?

Comment: I did end up getting it working,  All I had to do was move the media folder into the static folder, everything is working fine now. I'm not getting any errors. Any idea as to why lol?